# why am getting null value for the $mail->body =$message?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmailer

I have tried to add text in message finally it works but after adding `$message` from the form showing `null` with error message.

I am using an ajax call for form submission. Everything working fine but mail is not working throwing an error

> "message":"Mailer Error: Message body empty"

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");


$c_name = $_POST['name'];
$c_email = $_POST['email'];
$c_message = $_POST['message'];

$message = '<ul><li>' . $c_name . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $c_email . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $c_message . "</li></ul>";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();             // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "jswan";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "secret"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "from@example.com";
$mail->FromName = "Mailer";
$mail->AddAddress("josh@example.net", "Josh Adams");
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';


$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50        // add attachments

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Enquiry";
$mail->Body = preg_replace('/\[\]/','',$message);
//$mail->Body    = $message; //var_dump($message) showing null
$mail->AltBody = $message;

//$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if (!$mail->send()) { 
$result = array('status'=>"error", 'message'=>"Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);//
echo json_encode($result);
} else {
$result = array('status'=>"success", 'message'=>"Message sent.");
echo json_encode($result);
}
exit;
?>
```

**form.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{


$('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    debugger;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'form/index.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false ,
            success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            if(result.status=="success"){
                $('#success_message').show();
            }else if(result.status=="error"){
            $('#error_message').show();
            }
            },


        });

  });   
});
```

Comment: is your ajax sending message successfully?

Comment: Yes its working

Comment: After submission mail is not working and response data showing mailer body empty error

Comment: Do a var_dump of $_POST to see what you are really getting from your ajax call.